# send data to a python cgi script for processing from browser using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I have an html test file with the following

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var httprequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
        httprequest.open("POST","hello.cgi",true);
        httprequest.onload=function(){
        if(httprequest.status==200){
            alert("");
         }// end of if
         }//end of onload
         var content={"hello":"world"};
         httprequest.send(JSON.stringify(content));
         alert(httprequest.responseText)
          </script
    </body>
</html>
</doctype>
```

**In this scenario I am trying to send the data {"hello":"world"}; to a python cgi script**

This is my python script **that works well with data submitted from a `<form>`** html tag

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
    import sys
    import cgi
    import traceback
    print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    print "<h1>YES</h1>"
    formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print(formData)
    print(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

When I send the data `{"hello":"world"}`, my browser alert box shows no data returned from the cgi script.

As reflected in the cgi script, I am trying to print "YES" and print the data that was sent from javascript.

I have found several questions relating to use of `$.ajax` to do this but haven't come across a method using `XMLHttpRequest()`

**Question**

**How can I send data to a python cgi script for processing from my browser using pure javascript (no jquery)**

Comment: Your `alert()` happens long before the HTTP request has completed. It's an **asynchronous** operation.

Comment: okay..let me try this and see how this works...I am relatively new to JS

Comment: @Pointy..I moved "alert(httprequest.responseText)" and placed it inside  the onload function and this works..can you post an answer and elaborate a little on the asynchronous operations relating to the above codes..Much appreciated.....I am not sure I grasp the reason why it doesn't work outside the function

Comment: OK give me a sec - this is a question which is asked (with many variations) very often, because the way things work is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP request you're performing happens on its own time. The call to `httprequest.send()` **starts** the operation, but that function call returns almost immediately, and definitely before the remote server has responded. This *asynchronous* behavior is a basic fact of life in JavaScript environments.

The whole reason for the "onload" callback is to make it possible for you to write code that happens when the HTTP request actually completes. The browser will invoke that function with the results *when the results become available*. That might be in 100 milliseconds, or 10 seconds; it all depends on the server and the network.

Comment: I see...this is very helpful especially the emphasized parts  of the answer....:D

Comment: one more question..my output prints but the page shows that it is continously loading....any suggestions?

Comment: @repzero the loading indicator can be hard to control; I don't know all the ways it can be "confused". It could be that there's some unrelated resource that it's waiting for. The "Network" browser debugging tab might help you figure that out.